# dlopen fails with unable to locate symbol on Android

Tags: android, c++, cmake, dlopen

I'm building a binary executable to be run on Android with some shared library.
Builds, links and executes just fine but during execution is tries to load one of the shared libraries.
This fails because it's unable to locate a symbol from that library (supposedly).

```
void *handle = dlopen(_path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (0 != handle) {
    its_symbol = dlsym(handle, _symbol.c_str());
} else {
    std::cout << "Loading failed: (" << dlerror() << ")";
}
```

My questions are, what could be the cause and how can I fix or circumvent it?
The same works perfectly when built against linux.
What I tried:

- Checking cmake parameters
- Changing dlopen flags

Error message:

WARNING: linker: $library$: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x24c5
2017-06-21 05:08:02.223634 [error] Loading failed: (dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol $symbol$ referenced by $library$

Comment: After the failing dl*() function, you can call dlerror() to find out what was the problem.

Comment: Exactly, I added that error message to my post, thank you.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to tell what could be the problem. It seems that your $library$ refers to symbol in another library, and it cannot found it (it can have a lot of causes of this). Does this $library$ work in another program? Can you try this on a different android device?